# aggregate function in lit() of pyspark along with withColumn

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have column quantity in dataframe. I want to add a new column to this dataframe with each record having `min("Quantity")`. I am trying to use `lit()` in `pyspark`. something like below

```
df.withColumn("min_quant", lit(min(col("Quantity")))).show().
```

It's resulting in the getting below error

```
grouping expressions sequence is empty, and `InvoiceNo` is not an aggregate function. 
Wrap (min(`Quantity`) AS `min_quant`) in windowing function(s) or wrap
```

This is working:

```
df.withColumn("min_quant", lit(2)).show().
```

But, in place of 2 here, I want `min(Quantity)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: it is aggregate function but you are using it in the plain. Looking for the way to aggregate your data.

Comment: I am trying to add static value min(quantity) to all the rows of dataframe(Suppose hat minimum quantity is 5 the all my rows should have value 5 in column min_quant). like how we add current_date() to all the rows of datafarme ----> df.withColumn("today", lit(current_date())).show(10,False)

Comment: I am trying to get to the concept that why I am not able to do this with aggregate functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using window function as min() function needs aggregation.

```
val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("InvoiceNo")

df.withColumn("min_quant", min("Quantity") over(windowSpec)).show()
```

Sample Result:

```
+---------+----+--------+---------+
|InvoiceNo|name|Quantity|min_quant|
+---------+----+--------+---------+
|        1| ABC|      19|        1|
|        1| ABC|       1|        1|
|        1| ABC|       8|        1|
|        1| ABC|     389|        1|
|        1| ABC|     196|        1|
|        2| CBD|      10|        1|
|        2| CBD|     946|        1|
|        3| XYZ|       3|        1|
+---------+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi Anup, this giving me minimum quantity over invioce_no specification. whereas I am trying to add static value. suppose the least quantity is 5 then all my rows should have 5 and min_quant. like how I am adding current_date to all the rows in the column 'today' ----> df.withColumn("today", lit(current_date())).show(10,False)

Comment: Hi Ali, this should not take minimum quantity over invoice_no as there is no partition by this should take the minimum quantity over the dataframe. I am editing the answer with sample result

Comment: Thanks, Anup. I got the expected output and I learned window functions as well.